# Git and WordPress (+ managing plugins and media)

Tags: git, version-control, github, wordpress

I'd like to apply revision control - using git - to my WordPress-based website development.

Based on my concerns below, how do I go about?

**Concern 1: Pushing "granular changes"**
In this specific case, it is hard to mimic the webserver environment locally. Therefore, I would like to push changes very often. Could I push changes on a "sub-commit level" to the webserver to avoid "irrelevant" commits? (And do I have to set up a git repo on my remote webserver at all?)

**Concern 2: Plugin and media handling**
Previously, me and my colleagues have been installing/updateing plugins and uploaded media from WordPress' admin interface. If I'd also like to keep media and plugins in sync, how would this be achieved?

I would appreciate any resources detailing how to set up a workflow which would allow me to keep all my files (WordPress + plugins, media, themes etc.) locally, while at the same allowing me to push "granular changes" to my webserver and "real commits" to Github.

Comment: What did you end up doing with plugin and media handling? I am trying to figure out the same part of my workflow right now.

Comment: Hi @JosiahSprague, I do all the dev. locally (incl. plugin installations) and use WordPress skeleton https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton to separate core WP from my modifications. The skeleton also separates media which is a good practice as you may want to serve this from another location.

Comment: Cool. That's similar to what I ended up with on my last project, but I don't like how the content directory is outside of the Wordpress directory, simply because some poorly written plugins aren't compatible with that setup.

Comment: What do you do with this setup when you want to add a plugin that doesn't exist as a git repo? For example, Google Analytics for Wordpress by Yoast. Do you just copy the files into the plugins folder and commit them straight to your git repo? Do you add them to git ignore? Do you mirror the SVN repo in git? Or do you do something else that I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding Concern1, you can isolate those micro changes in a branch.

Basically, your local repo has two branches:

- one dedicated to your granular commits
- one (master) for GitHub

You can push everything to:

- your website, on a bare repo, and then clone it and checkout the "granular" branch.
- GitHub, with master updated with the "real" commits.

To clean your history and build your real commits, you can [rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) the granular branch on top of master in an interactive way:

```
git checkout master
git rebase -i granular
```

That was you pick, squash or edit commits made in granular, replaying a cleaner set of commits on master.
That rewrites granular history, but this is not too bad if nobody pull directly from this branch.
If you want to preserve the granular history, only `merge` or `cherry-pick` some commits from `granular` to `master`.

There are several example of managing Wordpress with Git:

- [Keeping Wordpress up to date using Git](http://www.matusiak.eu/numerodix/blog/index.php/2008/09/21/git-by-example-keeping-wordpress-up-to-date/) (Apr. 2008)
- [Tracking WordPress with Git](http://ianloic.com/2008/09/06/tracking-wordpress-using-git/) (Sept. 2008)
- [git by example – upgrade wordpress like a ninja](http://www.matusiak.eu/numerodix/blog/index.php/2008/09/21/git-by-example-keeping-wordpress-up-to-date/) (Sept. 2008)

The last link is the most detailed about the WordPress upgrade process, and ends also with a rebase of your modifications;